# Why I cannot find suitable ARIMA model for the dataset?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, seasonality, acf-pacf

I have a monthly dataset. I applied ADF test and saw that this dataset is stationary. Also, Canova-Hansen test is applied to see if there is stochastic or deterministic seasonality. As you see below the dataset is stationary and it shows deterministic seasonality.

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  rainfall
Dickey-Fuller = -5.1491, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


    Canova and Hansen test for seasonal stability

data:  rainfall

      statistic pvalue  
Jan      0.1378 0.4886  
Feb      0.3668  0.092 .
Mar      0.2485 0.2116  
Apr      0.2401 0.2248  
May      0.1674 0.3885  
Jun      0.1745 0.3677  
Jul      0.0541 0.9246  
Aug      0.1059 0.6304  
Sep      0.1084 0.6179  
Oct      0.1546 0.4286  
Nov      0.0565 0.9118  
Dec      0.0828 0.7567  
joint    1.5638 0.4809  
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Test type: seasonal dummies 
NW covariance matrix lag order: 14 
First order lag: no 
Other regressors: no  
P-values: based on response surface regressions
```

[image: Autocorrelation Function]
[image: Partial Autocorrelation Function]

I did not find the suitable ARIMA model for this dataset. I runned `auto.arima` function with `xreg=seasonaldummy(dataset)` in RStudio suggested ARIMA(0,0,0) as a best model. I tried alternative models by looking ACF and PACF plots but alternative models has very low R^2 values.

Seasonality cannot be detected from time series plots and ACF plots, but Canova-Hansen test validated the existence of seasonality. Also, I think there is an indication o seasonality because dataset has lower values for summer season. Is there any recommendation about how to find suitable ARIMA model?

Comment: It would be really helpful to have a plot of your raw data and then some idea of what you are trying to achieve by applying the model you are. Can you provide that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general rule saying that at least one of the ARIMA orders must be nonzero. There are time series for which ARIMA(0,0,0) is a suitable model. In your case, it seems there are no ARIMA patterns beyond deterministic seasonality that you already have modelled using dummy variables. That is in line with the ACF and PACF plots. If you did not include seasonal dummies, you would probably have a seasonal AR(1) model, but that need not be the better alternative compared to seasonal dummies. You are probably fine the way you have done it now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Professor. ARIMA(0,0,0) model for this dataset has 0.25 $R^2$  value. This low R square value made me think more. Even though I aware that R square is not only measure, I always think that I cannot continue for this analysis because R square is not high.

Comment: @iloloa, what can be considered high vs. low is highly dependent on the context. Do you know of similar studies that have achieved much higher $R^2$ with the same type (and frequency) of data for a site where rainfall is about as predictable as in your case?